# How to initialize an array when using template<typename T> C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Normally if I for example have `string array[10]` I can initialize all spots in the array like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    array[i] = "";
```

or if it is an array with pointers I write `array[i] = nullptr` instead, but how do I initialize when the type is more general like `T array[10]`?

Comment: What do you want to initialize the values to?

Comment: You can call T's default constructor T()

Comment: `std::string` cannot have the value `nullptr`.

Comment: @erip I meant that I use nullptr if I have an array with pointers not when using string

Comment: Why do you want to initialize a `std::string` to `""`? That's what the default constructor does anyway. I've never understood why people think you need to set a `std::string` to the empty string ... what value do you think it would have if you didn't do that?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Beginners fear junk values. :)

Comment: Also note that for things that are default constructable like `std::string` when you do `std::string arr[10]` each element in the array is already set to `""` for you.

Answer (score 8):

If value-initialization is all you need, then you can value-initialize all array members with empty braces:

```
T array[10]{};
//         ^^
```

Or:

```
T array[10] = {};
```

Value-initialization produces the zero or null value for scalars, value-initializes each member for aggregates, and calls the default constructor for non-aggregate class types.

(If you want to initialize your array elements with values other than `T{}`, then you need something more complex and specific.)

Comment: But you're assuming it's a definition; `array` could be a pointer passed to i.e. a function. Still, it's the best solution if not.

Comment: @black: I don't understand. What other kinds of initialization are there?

Comment: It's basically what NathanOliver said: you can use `T a[N] {};` if you're defining that variable, but you can't if it has already been (and perhaps passed later to a function that performs the actual init.). Again, it's more a detail and probably not the OP's problem.

Comment: @black, that would not be "initializing" then, because technically you can only "initialize" something in a definition ... but the OP might be using "initializing" in the same way (i.e. to mean simply setting to a value, possibly replacing existing values).

Comment: Right, there might be another question here about how to assign values to all array elements. To which I would respond `std::fill` :-)

Answer (score 4):

Well you could do like the standard does and use an initialization function in the form of

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void initialize(T (&arr)[N], const T& value = T())
{
    for(auto& e : arr)
        e = value;
}
```

Now you can call this and not pass a value and the array with be initialized with default value or you can specify a value and the array will be initialized with that value.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to call the default constructor on all elements of the array, you can use value-initialization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  // value-initialize `array` which value-initializes all elements of `array`.
  A() : array() {}
  T array[10];
};

int main() {
    A<int> ints;

    for(auto e: ints.array) {
        assert(e == 0);
    }

    A<std::string> strings;

    for(auto e: strings.array) {
        assert(e.empty());
    }

    A<int*> int_ptrs;

    for(auto e: int_ptrs.array) {
        assert(e == nullptr);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: value-initialization is different to "call the default constructor on all members" .

Comment: @M.M XY problem solved with value-initialization; i.e., calling default ctor/zero initialization is a part of value-initialization.

Comment: @M.M Oops, I meant elements, not members. Corrected the typo.